# Cytoscape: convert XML to dagre layout

Tags: jquery, json, xml, cytoscape.js

Is it possible in Cytoscape to use XML as input and parse that XML into a dagre layout? I have looked through the [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/initialisation) but I can't seem to find any information on XML importation.

One possiblity I can think of is parsing the XML as JSON and using that as input, but I'm not sure what would happen with the attributes of XML. Are they lost? How are they made accessible via the generated node (in the DOM, or through JavaScript (or jQuery))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that serialize a XML code to JSON. I have done the inverse operation that you are looking for once (converting the graph to a XML code) using [XMLWriter](http://flesler.blogspot.de/2008/03/xmlwriter-for-javascript.html):

```
function createXmlCode() {
  var xw = new XMLWriter();
  xw.formatting = 'indented'; //add indentation and newlines
  xw.indentChar = ' '; //indent with spaces
  xw.indentation = 4; //add 2 spaces per level
  xw.writeStartDocument();
  xw.writeStartElement('root');
    //go on, make some for each like
    //$.each(cy.$('node'), function(k, v) { ... }
    //$.each(cy.$('edge'), function(k, v) { ... }
  xw.writeEndElement();
  var output = xw.flush();
  xw.close();
  return output;
}
```

It should not be difficult to do the reverse. I made it two-ways, but only for JSON. I used:

```
cy.add(JSON.parse("[" + $("#json").text() + "]"));
```

So I could parse a JSON input from a text-box named #json directly to #cy.

Hope this helps.